# How to configure "Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI)" for sparql endpoint query page in virtuoso?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

How do I set default graph IRI similar to what is seen at http://dbpedia.org/sparql, which automatically populates default graph IRI?

[image]
I have added the following in `virtuoso.ini` but no luck

```
[SPARQL]
;ExternalQuerySource        = 1
;ExternalXsltSource         = 1
DefaultGraph               = http://dbpedia.org
;ImmutableGraphs           = http://localhost:8890/dataspace
ResultSetMaxRows           = 2000000
MaxQueryCostEstimationTime = 4000   ; in seconds
MaxQueryExecutionTime      = 600    ; in seconds
DefaultQuery               = select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100
DeferInferenceRulesInit    = 0  ; controls inference rules loading
;PingService            = http://rpc.pingthesemanticweb.com/
ShortenLongURIs            = 1
```

Comment: Look into the Virtuoso conductor, maybe it's there. And are you sure that this config file is used and not any other located somewhere else?

Comment: @AKSW I found some documentation here which uses web interface to upload quads and set uri - https://github.com/dbpedia/dbpedia-docs/wiki/Loading-Data-Virtuoso. But I'd like to setup using script/configs. BTW I had setup my dbpedia endpoint using aksw's docker scripts from https://github.com/AKSW/DBpedia-docker, thanks for these scripts.

Comment: @AKSW apparently it was not using new `virtuoso/virtuoso.ini` file from virtuoso folder when I restarted the container. it was taking from the one that was there in `db` folder. editing that file solved the issue.

Comment: Ah, yeah - thta's what I thought might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, you must edit the INI file that's associated with the DB file, for the Virtuoso instance in question.

Typically, the INI and DB files are found in the same directory, but this is not mandatory.

When they are in different directories, the INI file will include a filepath to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Using *isql*, you can specify graph as:

```
define input:default-graph-uri <http://localhost:8890/DAV/elec1>
```